# phong and goraud shading - need knowledge about how the fragments get shaded

Tags: opengl, shader

The only practical difference about Phong shading and Goraud shading is that if the calculation of fragment color is done in the vertex shader then it's Goraud else it's phong. I've got a little code of vertex shader and fragment shader code below:

```
//vertexShader.vs
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}  


//FragmentShader.fs
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 Normal;  
in vec3 FragPos;  

uniform vec3 lightPos; 
uniform vec3 viewPos; 
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 objectColor;

void main()
{
    // ambient
    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    // specular
    float specularStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0),32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor;  

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

It turns out the Phong is a bit more smooth looking on low poly objects. So, the knowledge barrier is basically in how the fragments get shader. First let's look at what the [wonderful resource learnopenGL](http://learnopengl.com) already provides.

In summary, it tells us that the color value supplied at the vertices are interpolated within the boundary of the fragment made by the vertices. So, this is quite meaningful like something like an weighted average is taken for the colors making the vertices.

But, like **Phong shading model** where the calculation is done right in the fragment shader, what happens? How are the fragment pixels shaded? Say there are three vertices then is the fragment fully colored with the first color, fully with second and then with third and is the total median of the colors taken or something? How is the fragment shaded when the calculated within the fragment shader?

Comment: "*How are the fragment pixels shaded?*" By executing the fragment shader. The fragment shader is code that determines the color of a fragment. You run the code; that's how the fragment gets its color.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes of course. But, run the code with what output color, please read my last paragraph. 3 vertices with 3 different colors that aren't interpolated since code for each pixel is given. which color does it take? an average of three? sum of three? some factor of the three colors?

Comment: "*3 vertices with 3 different colors*" What colors? I see no colors being *given* to your fragment shader. I see them *computing* colors, but those colors don't come from the inputs, do they?

Comment: @NicolBolas , yes exactly my point, no color is being given, the output color depends on the Position of vertex and Normal only, but there are only three of them which comes as constant fromt the vertex shader, and yet the surface is smooth in phong and not in goroud. That is why there is some thing remaining to understand on how the pixel get calculated

Comment: The vertex shader is executed once for each vertex. The fragment shader is executed once for each fragment. The outputs of the vertex shader are interpolated depending on the [Barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the fragment on the triangle primitive and that's the input to the fragment shader.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , thanks for mentioning the barycentric coordinates but, my actual point is: if we are doing our own calculation like above, for _each_ pixel of the fragment, then there is no place for such interpolation, right? then the fragment should be uniformly colored. But this is not the case as we can see in Phong model, we get interpolation of colors, so I was asking how's the fragment being shaded.

Comment: @juztcode No. The input to the fragment shader is is differnt for each fragment (because it is interpolated).  `Normal` and `FragPos` are different for each fragment. Each triangle has 3 corners., `Normal` and `FragPos` are computed for each corner of the triangle int the vertex shader. The attributes for the corners are interpolated fore each fragment which is covered by the triangle.

Comment: you mean each pixel in the fragment has it's own interpolated value for the `Normal` and `FragPos` ? Can you tell me how do we verify this, is there a way of obtaining each interpolated values maybe .?

Comment: @juztcode: There's no such thing as "pixel in the fragment". A fragment is the name for the pixel-sized area that the rasterizer cuts primitives into. Each *fragment* will be processed by the fragment shader, and each fragment has its own interpolated value for all inputs to the fragment shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas , which means all three vertices are taken into account for each fragment(the smallest unit of a ... triangle in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertex shader is executed once for each vertex. The fragment shader is executed once for each fragment. The outputs of the vertex shader are interpolated depending on the [Barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the fragment on the triangle primitive and that's the input to the fragment shader.
The input to the fragment shader is different for each fragment (because it is interpolated).

In you special case this means that, `Normal` and `FragPos` are different for each fragment. Each triangle has 3 corners. `Normal` and `FragPos` are computed for each corner of the triangle in the vertex shader. The attributes for the corners are interpolated for each fragment which is covered by the triangle and that interpolated vectors are the input to the fragment shader.
Since each fragment has a different input (`Normal` and `FragPos`) the comuted output (`FragColor`) is different for each fragment.
The output is just slightly different for neighboring fragments, because the input differs only slightly, too. That causes the smooth lighting.

Note, even if the normal vector (`Normal`) is a face normal (the same normal for the 3 vertices), then still `FragPos` is different.

Furthermore the spcular highlight (`float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0),32)`) is not a linear function. Thus the specular highlight can't be computed correctly by a linear interpolation. It has to be computed per fragment.
Actually there is a difference if `Normal` and `FragPos` are interpolated and `result` is computed in the fragment shader, in compare when `result` is computed in the vertex shader and is interpolate through the fragments.

---

The vertex attributes are the input to the vertex shader. The output of the vertex shader is interpolated (always) and the interpolated values are the input to the fragment shader ([Rasterization](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview#Rasterization)). The output of the fragment shader is written to the framebuffer:

vertex attrtibutes -> vertex shader -> interpolation/rasterization -> fragment shader -> framebuffer.

So, there is a difference if you interpolate `Normal` and `FragPos` and compute `result` in the fragment shader or if you compute `result` in the vertex shader and interpolate `result`

For a further information about the rendering pipeline see [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).

Comment: I didn't quite get this part: "The output is just slightly different for neighboring fragments, because the input differs only slightly, too. That causes the smooth lighting. " and along with the thing that, if the values are interpolated regardless of whether we put the `Normal` and `FragPos` in any of the shaders, then why the difference in smoothness, they're interpolated by the same value right? Why does the placing of code affect interpolation values?

Comment: @juztcode I think you don't get the basic. Read the first paragraph carefully. Note, the fragment shader is executed many more times than the vertex shader. The fragment is executed for each fragment (pixlel) which is covered by a triangle. The vertex shader is execute 3 times (each corner) of a triangle. So there are 3 output values of the vertex shader for `Normal` and `FragPos`. This 3 outputs have to assigned to may inputs of the fragment shader (for each pixel). Thus the outputs have to be interpolated and The input of neighboring fragments is just slightly different.

Comment: I do get the point that there is an individual value of normal and fragment position for each fragment/pixel , but my point was there must be two interpolation methods while we define goraud and phong models in vertex and fragment shader respectively. Otherwise there would be no shading difference. I think gkv311 in his answer tells us these two methods but how does openGL select this based on where we define code is a mystery to me, do you know?

Comment: @juztcode No there are not 2 interpolation methods.  You didn't read may answer. `spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0),32)` is not a linear function. So there is a difference if you interpolate `Normal`  and `FragPos` and compute `result` in the fragment shader or if you compute `result` in the vertex shader and interpolate `result`.

Comment: your last remark had just made a bit sense to me and I read above where gkv311 says in above comment: "Computing color in Fragment Shader leads to no interpolation, it is a final color (save some operations like stencil test and similar) " , which quite mismatches what you say. it's a bit confusing......

Comment: @juztcode *"Computing color in Fragment Shader leads to no interpolation"* - is misleading. That answer is a bad answer. He means that the output of the fragment shader is not interpolated. Of course the output of the vertex shader is interpolated (always)! The output of the vertex shader is interpolated and the interpolated values are the input to the fragment shader. The output of the  fragment shader is written to the framebuffer. vertex attrtibutes -> vertes shader -> interplolation -> fragment shader -> framebuffer.

Comment: oh, so no interpolation in the fragment shader? just another curious bit, we could check how many times a shader executed in the CPU side using something like a counter variable or print statements, how'd you do something similar in the GPU side for the shaders? Any tool/methods you know of?

Answer (score 6):

The difference between Phong an Gouraud shading is that:

- **Gouraud** *averages **colors***.
  Color is computed based on vertex normal by Vertex Shader and then averaged between fragments of a single triangle based on the distance from each triangle vertex.
- **Phong** *averages **normals***.
  Color is computed by Fragment Shader based on averaging of 3 vertex normals of triangle passed through from Vertex Shader.

On high-polygonal mesh both give very close result, as dispersion of per-triangle colors become smaller.

On low-poly mesh, averaging shaded colors in **Gouraud** gives worse visual result, because averaging colors has close to none physical meaning.

Averaging normals within **Phong** shading simulates smooth surface properties, so that their averaging might be close or even match original analytical surface definition, leading to much more reasonable and smooth visual results.

The averaging is done not by Shader program itself, but by a fixed hardware functionality between Vertex and Fragment shader stages. So that when you compute color or pass-through normal / UV coordinates and similar in Vertex Shader, these values are interpolated by hardware between 3 vertices across all fragments inside triangle based on fragment *barycentric coordinates*.

The color computed within Fragment Shader is a final one (before applying Blending or Stencil test, which are also done by fixed hardware functionality). So that putting lighting computation inside Vertex of Fragment shader defines what will be interpolated and what is computed directly.

Comment: but in the GLSL code above, no averaging of color nor normal is being done, the reason for the smoothness is given in most sources as: because it's computed in the fragment shader it's smooth , that's not very reasonable, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: The averaging is done not by Shader but by fixed hardware functionality - **out** parameters passed from Vertex Shader to Fragment Shader as **in** parameters are interpolated. Check the Rendering Pipeline. Although it is called as Programmable, it still contains a lot of fixed-function steps: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview

Comment: okay I get it a bit  combined with Rabbid76 and your answer/comments , but how does openGL select one method of interpolation based on where we define the code?  How does it know whether to average normals or average colors

Comment: **Fragment Shader** computes a **color** of a very single fragment, **Vertex Shader** computes attributes of a very single **vertex**. Passing attributes from Vertex to Fragment shader results in interpolation (triangle defines a set of fragments). Computing color in Fragment Shader leads to no interpolation, it is a **final color** (save some operations like stencil test and similar).